# GeoPandas: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file'. Did you mean: 'to_pickle'?

Tags: python, geopandas, attribute-joins

I am at a complete loss, I have looked at other posts to no avail.

Following is the code I am trying to execute:

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd


root_dir = r"C:\Users\s.oneill\Desktop\SAMPLE\SHP"
main_folder = None
join_folder = None

# Defines the COV_ and FLT_ folder paths in the root directory \SHP
for folder_name in os.listdir(root_dir):
    folder_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder_name)
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        if folder_name.startswith('COV_'):
            main_folder = folder_path
        elif folder_name.startswith('FLT_'):
            join_folder = folder_path

print("Main folder:", main_folder)
print("Join folder:", join_folder)

# Find the main shapefile in the main_folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main_folder, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            main_shp = os.path.join(root, file)


# Find the shapefile to join in the join_folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(join_folder, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            join_shp = os.path.join(root, file)

print("Main shapefile:", main_shp)
print("Join shapefile:", join_shp)

# Read the .shp as GeoDataFrame
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(main_shp)
gdf2 = gpd.read_file(join_shp)

# Set unique ID
Ukey = 'Flightline'

# Perform attribute join retaining all values from both Dataframes

merged_gdf = gdf1.merge(gdf2, on=Ukey, how='outer')

# Outputs joined dataframe as Shapefile

output_shapefile = os.path.splitext(main_shp)[0] + "_join.shp"
output_shapefile_path = os.path.join(root_dir, output_shapefile)
print(output_shapefile)
merged_gdf.to_file(output_shapefile)
```

I continue to receive this error and I have not found any solution elsewhere online:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonScripts\CovFltMerge.py", line 53, in <module>
    merged_gdf.to_file(output_shapefile)
  File "C:\Users\s.oneill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file'. Did you mean: 'to_pickle'?
```

Comment: Looks like `merged_gdf` is a DataFrame and not a GeoDataFrame.  Not sure why this is.  The `merge()` output should have been a GeoDataFrame if it was run for a GeoDataFrame.  This implies that at some point you are getting a DataFrame and where you are expecting a GeoDataFrame.  (You could add some debugging `print()` statements to confirm this at various points.)

Comment: I agree with @Son of a Beach comment, something is wrong with either `read_file` or `merge`. I would be curious to see the types of gdf1 and gdf2. Based on [the docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas-read-file), `gpd.read_file` can return a mere DataFrame, so maybe you could try adding `ignore_geometry=False` the `read_file` (not sure this will work though). If that doesn't work out I would be curious to see the contents of your shapefiles.

Comment: print(type(gdf1))
print(type(gdf2))
Provides the following: 
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>

print(type(merged_gdf))
Provides the following 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

It seems that at the merge step the geodataframe is converted to a Dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That way of merging is creating a Pandas DataFrame. Try this:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/data/LMV/LMV-data_2021-10/ok_riks_Sweref_99_TM_shape/oversikt/riks/ak_riks.shp")

gdf1 = df.head(10)
gdf2 = df.tail(10)

print(type(gdf1.merge(gdf2, on="LANSKOD", how="outer"))) #This is creating a pandas df
#pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

merged = gpd.pd.merge(gdf1, gdf2, on="LANSKOD", how="outer")
print(type(merged))
#<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'> #Now it is a geopandas df

merged["geometry"] = merged["geometry_x"].combine_first(merged["geometry_y"]) #Create a complete geometry column
merged = merged.drop(columns=["geometry_x", "geometry_y"])
merged.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/testmerge.shp")
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!